# JDO persists all fields as null

Tags: java, google-app-engine, persistence, jdo, datanucleus

I have the following case:

An "Account" class, which should contain a colleciton of "Money" objects.

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Account extends Entity {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private String id;

    @Expose
    @Persistent
    private String name;

    /**
     * The initial balance should be a portfolio, e.g. 300 BGN, 230 EUR etc.
     */
    @Expose
    @Persistent
    private List<Money> initialBalancePortfolio;
```

The "Money" class looks this way:

```
public class Money {
    @Persistent
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.unindexed", value = "true")
    private BigDecimal ammount;

    @Persistent
    private String currency;
```

Here come the problems:

1. I do not want a separate table for all money instances. I tried to achieve it as I used @Embedded annotation, but it was not possible since initialBalancePortfolio cannot be embedded itself (Collection).
2. I gave up and tried to store the account object (pm.makePersistent(...)). I was hoping that this way the money object will be stored as well. This was actually true, but all of the object fields were null.

This test case shows the issue:

```
    @Test
    public void initialBalancePortfolioShouldBePersisted() throws Exception {
        //create
        Account account = createAccount();
        AccountDao accountDao = new AccountDao();
        accountDao.create(account);
        //get it with new dao
        AccountDao newAccountDao = new AccountDao();
        Account newAccount = newAccountDao.readAll().get(0);
        assertEquals(account.getInitialBalancePortfolio(), newAccount.getInitialBalancePortfolio());
    }

    private Account createAccount() {
        //create list with money
        List<Money> money = new ArrayList<Money>();
        Money m1 = new Money(23, "BGN");
        Money m2 = new Money(21, "EUR");
        money.add(m1);
        money.add(m2);
        //create account 
        Account account = new Account(accEntity, money, "xxx");
        return account;
    }
```

And JUnit Exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[Money [ammount=23, currency=BGN], Money [ammount=21, currency=EUR]]> but was:<[Money [ammount=null, currency=null], Money [ammount=null, currency=null]]>
```

**EDIT:**

Persistence code for object creation:

```
/**
 * Create entity. entityDao.create(entity);
 * 
 * @param t
 *            Entity
 * @return operations success
 */
public boolean create(T t) {
    if (t.getId() == null) {
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getInstance().getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            pm.makePersistent(t);
            LOGGER.info(getEntityClass() + " created!");
            return true;
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    } else {
        LOGGER.info(getEntityClass() + " already exist! Update only!");
        update(t);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and for object retrieval:

```
/**
 * Get all existing objects.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public List<T> readAll() {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getInstance().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        pm.getFetchPlan().setGroup(FetchGroup.ALL);
        Query q = pm.newQuery(getEntityClass());
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> allEntities = (List<T>) q.execute();
        return allEntities;
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: no persistence code posted, so leave people to guess whats in the DAO? not looked at the log seemingly also. Not looked at what 'state' your objects are in when you look at them (again you don't say where that is in your persistence code, so left to guesswork)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added my persitence code. I hope it will give you some additional information.

Comment: so what state are the objects in ? you don't say where you're checking the field values. More than likely you didn't detach them hence they're HOLLOW so obviously the fields are null (unless you set javax.jdo.option.RetainValues as per all JDO docs). This is what the log gives you. No idea why you're setting the FetchPlan when persisting, it's for FETCHing

Comment: I'm (JUnit is) checking the field values in the assertEquals statement. Look at the JUnit Exception. Can you tell my how to detach them (and where)? Thank you!

Comment: You detach by making them "detachable" in metadata, and then set detachOnClose (see DataNucleus docs - standard JDO). You imply by your title of this that nulls are persisted, yet still don't seem to present any evidence of this, instead presenting that what is retrieved is null (but then its HOLLOW, not managed, so will be null)

Comment: Ok. Thank you! Is there any problem with my solution? What is wrong with it?

Comment: ignoring the log means not understanding the problem. Putting things in a txn can change when lifecycle ops take place but all depends on persistence properties and we don't see which are set. There is nothing "wrong" with any solution if you get the answer you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to  the problem.

Some background information about how JDO manages the lifecycle of an object:
http://db.apache.org/jdo/state_transition.html

And the solution itself:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getInstance().getPersistenceManager();
Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
try {
    tx.begin();
    pm.makePersistent(t);
    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.severe("Exception by creating a new entity "
            + e.getMessage());
    tx.rollback();
} finally {
    pm.close();
}
```

As you can see, I am using a transaction to ensure that the object is in a valid state.